# Breeze.js failing with Could not load file or assembly System.Web.Http.OData, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata, breeze

I'm trying out Breeze.Js and everything compiles and i have a breeze-decorated controller, but when trying to access the data I receive an error about an assembly which breeze.js has referenced, but which i cannot find anywhere.

The assembly in question is System.Web.Http.OData, Version=4.0.0.0

The only place i've found something about this namespace is at https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/tree/master/src/System.Web.Http.OData but I cannot find any nuget package for it.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out the nuget package at http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData/.

Or do this from your package manager console.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData
```

Comment: Hi, your solution was mostly correct, i had the package already but had to remove it and reinstall the package. I believe it could be due to the fact that the solution was in a dropbox folder and being open two places at once.

Comment: I had to removed the Breeze package and the OData package. Then re-add the Breeze package. Failed merge on csproj file I my guess for how I ended up with the issue. The references were all still in place, but OData library was not loading.